# Creating Custom Date Function in Excel

Tags: excel, date

I am trying to code a date function in Excel using the Month and than the last two digits of the year. So for example I just have the numbers 1-12 in a column. Then I want to code them as follows. 1 is Jan-15, 2 is Feb-15,..June-15. Then 7 is July-14, 8 is Aug-14. However whenever I try to type in those it codes them as their respective month, the day and the year as 2015. I know I have to create a custom format date function, but how would I go about doing that in this case. I have seen some things, but many of times it is unclear. Could Someone help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e#__toc320186183) can help you out.

> Create a custom date format
>
> If you want to use a format that isn’t in the Type box, you can create your own. The easiest way to do this is to start from a format this is close to what you want.
>
> Select the cells you want to format.
>
> Press CTRL+1.
>
> In the Format Cells box, click the Number tab.
>
> In the Category list, click Date, and then under Type, pick a date format that is close to the format you want.
>
> Go back to the Category list, and pick Custom. Under Type, you’ll see the format code for the date format you picked in step 4. The built-in date format can’t be changed, so don’t worry about messing it up. The changes you make will only apply to the custom format you’re creating.
>
> In the Type box, make the changes you want using code from the table below.

According to the table there and your description I suppose you should use a custom format like:

mmm-yy